# Windows 10 "News and Interests" taskbar widget shows "No accounts connected". How to fix?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I've signed in to Windows using my Microsoft account, and the search dialog shows my account as well. However, the News and Interests widget doesn't and instead displays information based on my outgoing network location. It doesn't let me customize anything as well because news feeds are managed on [www.msn.com](http://www.msn.com) which isn't getting picked up (because no account is signed in with this widget).

[image]

Is there any fix to this?

Comment: See if you can repair the app. Start, Settings, Apps, scroll down to Microsoft News, click on it, Advanced Options, and Repair and Reset it.  Close out, restart and test.

Comment: @John There is neither a "Microsoft News" nor "News". I believe that widget is associated to the "Search" app (shows up as "Feed" in task manager).

Answer (score 1):

You can try using VPN global mode of Hongkong or Japanese lines, I opened the VPN of Hongkong line in the Chinese mainland, and Microsoft account was successfully landed. However, it is worth noting that "accounts without connection" will be displayed after closing VPN.

[image]